# Missing linux headers

Tags: makefile, module, kernel

I have been working on my driver module and I got a build error related to the kernel headers, I reinstalled the newest headers and now I get the following error when trying to make my module:

```
scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders.c:18:10: fatal error: classmap.h: No such file or directory
   18 | #include "classmap.h"
```

My make file for anyone wondering:

```
CONFIG_MODULE_SIG=n1

obj-m += kbuf.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated